# Cannot create property 'updatedAt' on string '415'

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an issue on update record while updating while 415 is id.

> Cannot create property 'updatedAt' on string '415'

I also add update field in model but still getting error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally this means you're trying to update a field that is null.

Comment: yes, but we can get it saved by doing;
db.Model.update({key:value})

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it was my mistake on passing parameter (using es6).

```
db.Model.update(value)
```

The correct syntax have to be:

```
db.Model.update({value})
```